# How to convert an S3 object to a Resource in springBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a video which is of S3Object type.

I am trying to convert it to a Resource using the following code.

```
Resource resource = new InputStreamResource(video.getObjectContent());
```

I get the following error

```
"InputStream has already been read - do not use InputStreamResource if a stream needs to be read multiple times"
```

Is it possible to read an S3Object directly as a Resource?

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

How to load S3 bucket file from a private bucket:

```java
//Make sure your credentials are in the aws credentials file or use .withCredentials()
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withRegion("us-east-1")
                .build();

if(!s3client.doesBucketExistV2(adfsProperties.keystoreBucket())) {
    throw new Exception.... //bucket not found
}

S3Object s3object = s3client.getObject("bucket-name", "file-name");
S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = s3object.getObjectContent();

Resource r = new InputStreamResource(inputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like before passing into InputStreamResource you stream used by some method. Or better approach if your s3 url is publicly accessible, then try like that

```
@Autowired
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
```

In method use as follows.

```
   Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(<s3 url>)
```

Comment: I managed to do this using ByteArrayResource instead of InputStreamResource.  ByteArrayResource allows to read multiple times from the stream.